# RVT alternative in Blender?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

**The Story:**

Recently, I have stepped into using Unreal Engine for environmental design, pairing it up with Blender's fantastic modeling features. For starters, real-time rendering in Unreal is *way* better than EEVEE! XD Anyways, I found a cool feature called RVT (**R**untime **V**irtual **T**exturing) that basically mixes a texture with another so the seam between a landscape and an object mesh is less visible. Really fascinating!

**The Question**:

So, I am wondering: **is there any sort of RVT-style node-setup in Blender?** My best guess is that it will have something to do with TexCoord nodes, mapped globally, so that way the ground texture stays the same regardless of where the mesh is. Secondly, the mesh's texture would have to be blended along the z-axis with the ground texture, most likely with a ColorRamp node. **I need help because I don't now exactly how to structure this in the shader node editor.**

*(Below): This is what I am trying to achieve in Blender:*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well, I ended up figuring it out myself!** *(Turns out I am better at Blender than I thought! XD)*

[image]

Actually pretty simple! Here is my node setup^^^(Nothing too fancy.)

Dragging the colorramp changes the mix height:

[image]

**2 things to note:**

1. If you wanted to use Principled BSDF shaders instead of my diffuses, you can! (I just used diffuse for fun)
2. You would need to make a second Mapping + Mix Height node group setup for displacement, if you used that.

**My Blend:** [image]

Comment: Also, if that second image doesn't play as a gif, click on it, and it should open normally.